# How to edit (add or remove field) return JSON using nodejs mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to edit my return json like add or remove some field...
here is my code

```
return await Ledgers.find(queryObj)
```

output (response) look like...

```
{        
        "masterId": 0,
        "deducteeType": null,
        "parentGuid": "4eb25490-8288-4841-a925-ed2512ad6d7b-00000014",
}
```

I want to add one more field in json and want remove existing...

Comment: You can set which fields to return from query like this `{ deducteeType : -1}` which means dont return that field. `1` means return that field from query. If you want to modify the returned object from query, just create a JS object and then use `delete` Operator to delete field and `returnedObject.newField = value` to add new field

Comment: var r = Ledgers.find(queryObj).toObject();
r.Name = 'test';

its giving error :
data not found. TypeError: Ledgers.find(...).toObject is not a function

Comment: i dont think you need to use `toObject`. i think `find` returns an array of objects. `findOne` returns single object if there is an object with given criteria. plus @ApoorvaChikara gave an answer that works.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `key` from the object you can use the delete operator like this:

```js
const obj = {name :'name 1', key: 'key 1'};
delete obj.name;
console.log(obj);
```

And when you say you want to add something, you can simply add key:

```js
 const obj = {name: 'name 1'};
 obj['key'] = 'key 1';
 console.log(obj);
```

For your example, assign that return data to the variable and make the changes.

```
const resp = await Ledgers.find(queryObj);
resp['key'] = 'key 1'
```

Also if you want to make it using mongodb, you can use projection like this:

```
const resp = await Ledgers.find({queryObj}, { deducteeType: 1, parentGuid: 1, _id: 0});
delete resp['parentGuid'];
resp['test'] = test;
console.log(resp);
```

This will only return the named properties from the find query expect the `_id`. Check here for more [details](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/).

Comment: BTW Im beginner in nodejs 

this is my code

          const obj = Ledgers.find(queryObj);;
          delete obj.masterId;
          console.log(obj);

but masterId still there in json response

Comment: Can you share the code how are you doing that?

Comment: 'const obj = Ledgers.find(queryObj);
delete obj.masterId; 
console.log(obj);'

Comment: You are doing it wrong, the find query returns the promise not the object. Try doing - const obj = await Ledgers.find(queryObj): and the run delete on obj.

Comment: can you plz share example

Comment: I want to add one field in output and want to remove some existing field as i have share question...

Comment: I'm not sure what specific example are you looking for, but I have added that in the answer. I suggest you to go through things like promises and async/await.